# Initialising a class from within a class ES6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, subclass, super

I have a `Carousel` class and a Carousel should be able to initialise `Thumbnails` which are tied to it if the correct option is present.

Currently I have the following:

#### carousel.js

```
import Thumbnails from './thumbnails'

export class Carousel {
  constructor( options ) {
    this.showThumbnails = options.showThumbnails
  }

  init() {
    if( this.showThumbnails ) {

      let thumbnails = new Thumbnails({
        slidesPerView : 6
      })
    }
  }
}
```

#### thumbnails.js

```
export class Thumbnails {
  constructor( options ) {
    this.slidesPerView = options.slidesPerView;  
    console.log( this );
  }
}
```

Where I have `console.log(this)` in thumbnails.js I receive an error saying that super should be called before this.

So I put `super( options )` in at the top of the constructor but I get an error when compiling that says super call is only allowed in derived constructor.

Any help on why I receive this error and the best way to setup the relationship between these two classes would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you posted all code of `thumbnails.js`? If you wrote `export class Thumbnails {/**/}`, you don't need to call `super()` at all. The question is why you try to print `this`?

Comment: @MaximShoustin thanks for your quick reply. I wanted to be able to use this  to set things like this.slidesPerView to be able to use it in other functions throughout the file. I was just printing this to see if it would return the thumbnail object. Any further help you can offer would be great :)

Comment: please post full error stacktrace

Comment: Ah sorry you're absolutely right, I don't need super at all. It's working fine now without it :) Thanks for your help!